# Updating jenkins plugin from source

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I currently have [Build User Vars Plugin 1.1](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin) installed in my Jenkins. Since version 1.1 of the plugin, there has been some important [changes](https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-user-vars-plugin/compare/build-user-vars-plugin-1.1...master) to the plugin code, and I want to pick them up. The question is what is the least amount of work to package up the hpi/jpi file that I can push on my Jenkins install that will contain latest changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly easy to build a plugin locally; you can then upload the hpi/jpi file to Jenkins via the Advanced tab in the plugin manager.

See the [Jenkins plugin tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial) for detailed steps.

Comment: Indeed, it was amazingly reasonable, I just had to install maven, download latest source, cd into top level (where `pom.xml` is) and run mvn install. That created a `target` folder with hpi that I deployed on Jenkins and voila!